# Sub or Function not defined when calling module to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Worksheet_Change script that I would like to parse into modules. The commented out section has been moved to a module with the subroutine "Alluma_Change". I get a "sub or function not defined" error with the call. I need to distribute this to my team, so I figured breaking the code into modules would allow them to just import when there are updates, but maybe that is not possible. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("F1")) Is Nothing Then

        If Range("F1").Value = "Both PT and Trad" Then
            Rows("37:72").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

        If Range("F1").Value = "Pass-Through Only" Then
            Rows("37:53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("54:72").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        If Range("F1").Value = "Traditional Only" Then
            Rows("37:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("54:72").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    End If

'Dim mail_margin As Range, specialty_margin As Range, x() As String
'Set mail_margin = Range("D15"): Set specialty_margin = Range("D16")
'
'    If Not Intersect(target, Range("H3")) Is Nothing Then
'
'        If Range("H3").Value = "Alluma" Then
'            mail_margin.Formula = mail_margin.Formula & "*0"
'            specialty_margin.Formula = specialty_margin.Formula & "*0"
'        Else
'            x() = Split(Range("d15").Formula, "*")
'            mail_margin.Formula = x(0) & "*" & x(1)
'            x() = Split(Range("d16").Formula, "*")
'            specialty_margin.Formula = x(0) & "*" & x(1)
'        End If
'
'   End If

Call Alluma_Change

End Sub
```

Module for reference:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Alluma_Change()

Dim mail_margin As Range, specialty_margin As Range, x() As String
Set mail_margin = Range("D15"): Set specialty_margin = Range("D16")

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("H3")) Is Nothing Then

        If Range("H3").Value = "Alluma" Then
            mail_margin.Formula = mail_margin.Formula & "*0"
            specialty_margin.Formula = specialty_margin.Formula & "*0"
        Else
            x() = Split(Range("d15").Formula, "*")
            mail_margin.Formula = x(0) & "*" & x(1)
            x() = Split(Range("d16").Formula, "*")
            specialty_margin.Formula = x(0) & "*" & x(1)
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Make it `Public` instead of `Private`.

Comment: But then you'll need to pass it a range... `target` will throw an error.

Comment: `Sub Alluma_Change(Target as Range)` should work, too...And use `Alluma_Change, Target` instead of `Call Alluma_Change`

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. move `Alluma_Change()` to a standard module
2. make it `Public` rather than `Private`
3. put `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the start of the event code
4. put `Application.EnableEvents=True` at the bottom of the event code
5. fix any undefined variables in `Alluma_Change()`